# xlwings function to find the last row with data

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwings

I am trying to find the last row in a column with data. to replace the vba function: `LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

I am trying this, but this pulls in all rows in Excel. How can I just get the last row.

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
wb = Workbook()
print len(Range('A:A'))
```

Comment: Currently, there's nothing ready-made implemented. But you can always work-around as explained [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/missing_features.html). Also look at [this](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/112)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consolidating the answers above, you can do it in one line:

```
wb.sheet.range(column + last cell value).Get End of section going up[non blank assuming the last cell is blank].row
```

Example code:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Range, constants

wb = xw.Book(r'path.xlsx')
wb.sheets[0].range('A' + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
```

Comment: one liners are never a good idea. Code should be like a poem. Not jibersih for someone who actually knows how to read and write chinese.

Answer (score 8):

We can use Range object to find the last row and/or the last column:

```
import xlwings as xw

# open raw data file
filename_read = 'data_raw.csv'
wb = xw.Book(filename_read)
sht = wb.sheets[0]

# find the numbers of columns and rows in the sheet
num_col = sht.range('A1').end('right').column
num_row = sht.range('A1').end('down').row

# collect data
content_list = sht.range((1,1),(num_row,num_col)).value
print(content_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is very much the same as crazymachu's answer**, just wrapped up in a function. Since version 0.9.0 of xlwings you can do this:

```
import xlwings as xw

def lastRow(idx, workbook, col=1):
    """ Find the last row in the worksheet that contains data.

    idx: Specifies the worksheet to select. Starts counting from zero.

    workbook: Specifies the workbook

    col: The column in which to look for the last cell containing data.
    """

    ws = workbook.sheets[idx]

    lwr_r_cell = ws.cells.last_cell      # lower right cell
    lwr_row = lwr_r_cell.row             # row of the lower right cell
    lwr_cell = ws.range((lwr_row, col))  # change to your specified column

    if lwr_cell.value is None:
        lwr_cell = lwr_cell.end('up')    # go up untill you hit a non-empty cell

    return lwr_cell.row
```

Intuitively, the function starts off by finding the most extreme lower-right cell in the workbook. It then moves across to your selected column and then up until it hits the first non-empty cell.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `Direction` by starting at the very bottom and then moving up:

```
import xlwings
from xlwings.constants import Direction
wb = xlwings.Workbook(r'data.xlsx')
print(wb.active_sheet.xl_sheet.Cells(65536, 1).End(Direction.xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 2):

One could use the VBA Find function that is exposed through api property (use it to find anything with a star, and begin your search from the first cell).

Example:

```
row_cell = s.api.Cells.Find(What="*",
                   After=s.api.Cells(1, 1),
                   LookAt=xlwings.constants.LookAt.xlPart,
                   LookIn=xlwings.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                   SearchOrder=xlwings.constants.SearchOrder.xlByRows,
                SearchDirection=xlwings.constants.SearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                       MatchCase=False)

column_cell = s.api.Cells.Find(What="*",
                      After=s.api.Cells(1, 1),
                      LookAt=xlwings.constants.LookAt.xlPart,
                      LookIn=xlwings.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                      SearchOrder=xlwings.constants.SearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                      SearchDirection=xlwings.constants.SearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                      MatchCase=False)

print((row_cell.Row, column_cell.Column))
```

Other methods outlined here seems to require no empty rows/columns between data.

source: https://gist.github.com/Elijas/2430813d3ad71aebcc0c83dd1f130e33

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xlwings as xw

cellsDown = xw.Range('A1').vertical.value

cellsRight = xw.Range('A1').horizontal.value

print len(cellsDown)

print len(cellsRight)
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Include some explanation

Answer (score 0):

python 3.6, xlwings 0.11

## Solutoin 1

To find last row with data, you should do some work both horizontally and vertically. You have to go through every column to determine which row is the last row.

```
import xlwings
workbook_all = xlwings.Book(r'path.xlsx')
objectiveSheet = workbook_all .sheets['some_sheet']
# lastCellContainData(), inspired of Stefan's answer.
def lastCellContainData(objectiveSheet,lastRow=None,lastColumn=None):
    lastRow = objectiveSheet.cells.last_cell.row if lastRow==None else lastRow
    lastColumn = objectiveSheet.cells.last_cell.column if lastColumn==None else lastColumn
    lastRows,lastColumns = [],[]
    for col in range(1,lastColumn):
        lastRows.append(objectiveSheet.range((lastRow, col)).end('up').row)
        # extract last row of every column, then max(). Or you can compare the next 
        # column's last row number to the last column's last row number. Here you get
        # the last row with data, you can also go further get the last column with data:
    for row in range(1,lastRow):
        lastColumns.append(objectiveSheet.range((row, lastColumn)).end('left').column)
    return max(lastRows),max(lastColumns)
    
lastCellContainData(objectiveSheet,lastRow=5000,lastColumn=300)
```

I added lastRow and lastColumn. To make the program more effective, you can set these parameters according to the approximate shape of the data you're dealing with.

## Solution 2

xlwings is honored for being wrapper of pywin32. I don't know if your situation allows for keyboard or mouse. If so, first you ctrl+tab switch to the workbook, then ctrl+a to select the region containing data, then you call `workbook_all.selection.rows.count`.

another way:
When you know where right bottom cell of your data locates faintly, say AAA10000, just call `objectiveSheet.range('A1:'+'AAA10000').current_region.rows.count`

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After a while none of the solutions were really intuitive to me, so I decided to compile the following:
**Code:**

```
import xlwings as Objxlwings
import xlwings.constants
def Return_RangeLastCell(ObjWS):
    return ObjWS.api.Cells.SpecialCells(xlwings.constants.CellType.xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

I tried to keep consistency with the way to call it from Excel to keep it simple

Then on my main code, I just call it like so:

```
ObjWS=Objxlwings.Book('Book1.xlsx').sheets["Sheet1"]
print(Return_RangeLastCell(ObjWS).Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting solutions. But maybe like this:

```
print(sheet.used_range.last_cell.row)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cody's answer will help under normal circumstances, but if your sheet have hidden rows at bottom like links: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obiBh.png), it will give the wrong row number.

Lets say, if your row counts of data is 10, and row[5:11] are hidden, i.e. actually last_row will be 10.

[code a] below will give you answer 5, [code b] below will give you answer 10.

code a:

```
ws = wb.sheets[your_sheet_name]
last_row = ws.range('A' + str(ws.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row  # return 5
```

code b:

```
ws = wb.sheets[your_sheet_name]
last_row_1 = ws.used_range.last_cell.row  # return 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columnr = 1 # any value just to define the variable
countrow = 7 # Number of rows before the first data row.
selectcolumn = 18 # Column used to find the first empty data cell


while columnr is not None :
    countrow = countrow + 1
    columnr = wsreportsheet.cells(countrow,selectcolumn).value

print (countrow)
```

Comment: "columnr" was just to skip the rows with titles that may exist in the  spreadsheet. "selectcolumn" is the column that new data will be added to the spreadsheet. "countrow" will the the row number with the first empty cell in the selected column.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the usual range expansion to read in a range of dynamic size:

```
with xw.Book("myfile.xlsx", mode="r") as book:
sheet1 = book.sheets[0]
data = sheet1["A1"].expand().value
```